# Выборка из XML по условию при выводе в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml, recyclerview

Получаю список адресов из файла `XML`, как сделать так что бы показывались только те, в которых поле `<city>` имеет город , например Москва. То есть отфильтровать для вывода только те айтемы в которых есть Москва.

очевидно, надо отфильтровать массив перед подачей в адаптер. Только не могу понять, как это правильно сделать.

Вот так получаю данные

```
if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {

                        bankItemList = response.body().bankItemList;

                        ArrayList<Bank.BankItem> p = new ArrayList<>(bankItemList);

                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                        adapter = new Adapter(p);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


                    }
```

В частности надо сделать выборку по полю

```
@Element
private String BankAddressRu;

 public String getBankAddressRu() {
        return BankAddressRu;
    }
```

из массива

Comment: что значит правильно? быстро? удобно? красиво? практично? это можно сделать разными способами. в Java можно перебрать массив for, или написать Predicate. в Java 8 или в Kotlin можно использовать filter. в Rx можно сделать разными способами, удобно использовать filter через flatMapIterable. Все они будут отличаться. Выбирайте. А желательно видеть что вы сделали, дабы дать ответ более так сказать точно

Comment: я добавил как получаю данные. Выборка нужна самая простая ибо будет производится только один раз без дальнейших расширений